# How to use if else if in button - flutter

Tags: flutter, button, conditional-statements

I have 2 buttons one is time in and other is time out.

Below are the condition which must follow for enable and disable the button.

**Time in** button will be **enable** when :

```
timeout != null  || timein == null //these timein and timeout values should comes from database, but in below code I am using variables and updating their values. i'm not using database values here.
```

and it's background color will be blue[500]

**Time in** button will be **disable** when :

```
timein != null && timeout==null //these timein and timeout values should comes from database, but in below code I am using variables and updating their values. i'm not using database values here.
```

and it's background color will change to blue[200]

**time out** button will be, **enable** when:

```
time in != null
```

**time out** button will **disable** when:

```
time in == null
```

This is what i have done.

```
var t1="";
  var t2="";
  var timeIn;
  var timeOut;
  var timeInText="                 Time in";
  var timeOutText="                 Time out";
  bool timeInBttonPressed=false;
  bool timeOutButtonPressed=false;
          timein=="" || timeout!="" ?
          RoundedButton(icon: Icon(Icons.timer,color: Colors.white),
          text:timeInText,
          bgcolor: timeInBttonPressed ?Colors.blue[200]:Colors.blue[500],
          press:(){
            setState(() {
                          timeInText="                 "+getTime;
                          //timein=getTime;
                          timeOutButtonPressed=true;
                          //timeInBttonPressed=true;
                          
                        });

          })
          
          //Time in, disable:
          :
          RoundedButton(icon: Icon(Icons.timer,color: Colors.white),
          bgcolor: Colors.blue[200],
          text:"                 "+timein,
          press:(){
            setState(() {
              timeInBttonPressed=false;
                          
                        });
          })
          ),
      
   
//Time out, disable 

 timein==""?
          RoundedButton(icon: Icon(Icons.timer_off,color: Colors.white),bgcolor: Colors.blue[200],
          text: "                 Time out",color: Colors.white,
          press: (){
            setState(() {
                          timeInBttonPressed=true;
                        });
          },
          )
//time out enable
          :
          RoundedButton(icon: Icon(Icons.timer_off,color: Colors.white,),
          text: timeOutText,
          color: Colors.blue[50],
          bgcolor: timeOutButtonPressed ?Colors.blue[500]:Colors.blue[200],
          press:(){
            setState(() {
                          timeOutText="                 "+getTime;
                          //timeout=getTime;
                          //timeOutButtonPressed=!timeOutButtonPressed;
                          timeInBttonPressed=true;
                        });
          })
```

It's not meeting my requirements, can u guys please check it and help me to fix where i am doing wrong.

-------------------EDIT QUESTION--------------------------

i have edit your answer , here is the code

```
Widget _timein() {
   //enable
    if(timeout != ""  || timein == "") {
      return RoundedButton(icon: Icon(Icons.timer,color: Colors.white),
              text:timeInText,
              bgcolor: timeInBttonPressed ?Colors.blue[200]:Colors.blue[500],
              press: () {
                setState(() {
                timeInText="                 "+getTime;
                timein=getTime;
                //print("t1  "+t1);
                timeInBttonPressed=true;
                    
                                });
                
              //Your OnPress Event
              });
    }
    //disable
      else if(timein != "" && timeout=="") {
      return RoundedButton(icon: Icon(Icons.timer,color: Colors.white),
              text:timeInText,
              bgcolor: Colors.blue[200]);
      } 
    }


     Widget _timeout(){
   //enable
      if(timein != "") {
        return RoundedButton(icon: Icon(Icons.timer,color: Colors.white),
              text:timeOutText,
              bgcolor: timeOutButtonPressed ?Colors.blue[200]:Colors.blue[500],
              press: () {
                setState(() {
                timeOutText="                 "+getTime;
                timeout=getTime;
                //print("t2   "+t2);
                //timeOutButtonPressed=true;      
                timeInBttonPressed=true; 
                                });
                
        });

      }
      //disable
      else if(timein == "") {
        return RoundedButton(icon: Icon(Icons.timer,color: Colors.white),
              text:timeOutText,
              bgcolor: Colors.blue[200]);
      }
 }
```

it works like, initially i got time in button enable and time out button disable which is correct, then when i click on time in button its text change to current time and it gets disable and time out button gets enable, which is correct, but when i click on time out button its text change to currect time but color doesn't change. i want to make it disable after click and time in button will get enable and vice versa.
hope u got my point.

Comment: In description you have mentioned timeout and timeout but in code snippet you are using t1 and t2?

Comment: yeah, i have mentioned these timein and timeout values are coming from database, but for testing (without using database) i am using variable

Comment: let me edit the post for ur ease, so u can understand

Comment: @MuhammadAhmed check the question now, i edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `"" != null`. You are comparing timeIn and timeOut with empty string. Another thing is to make a separate function to make it readable.

```
Widget _timer() {
 if(timeout != null  || timein == null) {
   return RoundedButton(icon: Icon(Icons.timer,color: Colors.white),
          text:timeInText,
          bgcolor: timeInBttonPressed ?Colors.blue[200]:Colors.blue[500],
          onPress: () {
           //Your OnPress Event
          })

 } else if(timein != null && timeout==null) {
   return RoundedButton(icon: Icon(Icons.timer,color: Colors.white),
          text:timeInText,
          bgcolor: timeInBttonPressed ?Colors.blue[200]:Colors.blue[500])
  } 
  else if(timein != null) {
    return RoundedButton(icon: Icon(Icons.timer,color: Colors.white),
          text:timeInText,
          bgcolor: timeInBttonPressed ?Colors.blue[200]:Colors.blue[500],
          onPress: () {
    //Your On Press Event
    })

  }
  else if(timein == null) {
    return RoundedButton(icon: Icon(Icons.timer,color: Colors.white),
          text:timeInText,
          bgcolor: timeInBttonPressed ?Colors.blue[200]:Colors.blue[500])
  }
```

When you want to disable click event don't add the property `onPress`
}

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not meeting my requirement, i edit my post can please check it.